# Warm water bath

Tags: human-biology

Why is it advised to take bath in warm water when we are sick?I know that as homeotherms we need to generate metabolic heat to adapt to the environment temperature.But what is the mechanism by which it makes people feel better(except those who are allergic to it)?

Comment: Why someone likes bathing in water at some particular temperature is just based on personal choice. Some people like cold water. Some people are also allergic to bathing in warm water.

Answer (score 7):

1) A hot bath, or soak in hot water raises our body temperature. Several benefits of this rise include:  Improved blood circulation, Improved lymph circulation, increased metabolism and calmer nervous system.

2) During this increased temperature your body releases endogenous opioid peptides, which are primarily endorphins.That’s why you might feel like a new person after a hot bath!([reference](http://tubyoga.com/benefits-of-a-hot-bath-why-it-feels-so-good/))

It apparently also takes your feeling of loneliness away ([reference](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2007555/How-soaking-warm-bath-stop-feeling-lonely.html))

Comment: It is a myth that sweating detoxifies you. See for example, http://www.uamshealth.com/?id=12247&sid=1

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton thx for pointing that out

Comment: @TheLastWord Can you edit your answer then, please? It is a good answer, except for the detox stuff. I promise to upvote it if you fix that ;-)

Comment: @JohnEye I edited it